# how to build a javascript object using an array and the map function?

Tags: javascript

I've got an **array of channels** that I want to transform into a **single object** (channelSettings) with a true / false **property for each channel**.

I've got it working using the below code but it seems verbose.  Is there are way to do it without the "temp" var?  If I can get ride of that, then I could get ride of the self executing function as well.

```
var channels = ["TV", "Billboard", "Spot TV"];


var channelSettings = function() {
    var temp = {};

    channels.map(function(itm, i, a) {
        var channel = itm.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");
        temp[channel] = false;
    });

    return temp;
}();
```

I guess I'm trying to get the map function to return an object with properties instead of an array.  Is this possible?  Is it mis-guided?  Suggestions?

This is what I'm hoping it looks like in the end:

```
var channels = ["TV", "Billboard", "Spot TV"];

var channelSettings = channels.map(function(itm, i, a) {
        var channel = itm.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");
        return ????;
});
```

Comment: It may be a bit verbose, but it's also _clear_. I'd vote to leave it as it is.

Comment: just wanna add that the keys can have spaces and capital letters. for better consistency.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use a `.reduce()` function instead.

```
var channelSettings = channels.reduce(function(obj, itm) {
        var channel = itm.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");
        obj[channel] = false;

        return obj;
}, {});
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/MjW9T/

---

The first parameter references the previously returned item, except for the first iteration, where it references either the first item in the Array, or the seeded item, which we provided as an empty object.

The second parameter references the current value in the Array. As long as we always return `obj`, the first parameter will always be that object, as will the final return value.

Answer (score 5):

The [`map`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.19) function takes an array, and returns an array. Nothing else. But you can use [`reduce`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.21):

```
var settings = ["TV", "Billboard", "Spot TV"].reduce(function(obj, item) {
   obj[item.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "")] = false; // probably too concise
   return obj // yay, we can skip a semi-colon here :-P
}, {});
```

Well, "am not i am" beat me to it, but anyway:
`map` not only returns arrays, but also only returns arrays of the same length as the original. It's meant for transforming one array's values 1:1 into a new array. `reduce` is meant to "reduce an array to a single value". Hence its use here.

If you use a straight `for` loop or the `forEach` method to add properties to an object, you do need to declare that object. So, no, you can't do without `temp` in your code (unless you use `reduce` instead of a loop).

More information on MDN:

1. map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
2. reduce: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: and an excellent explanation here too!   (I wouldn't have to defend my green check determination in court..)   many thx!

Comment: @RobG Ah, MDN links - I completely forgot to add those. Thanks for the edit

Comment: I ended up using a more clear version.    
 
var key =item.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");   
obj[key] = false;
   return obj

Answer (score 0):

hmm..  looks like wrapping it in a function like this would do it.

```
function toObject(arr) {
  var rv = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
    if (arr[i] !== undefined) rv[arr[i]] = true;
  return rv;
}
```