# How to add custom property of object using .map

Tags: javascript

I'm using the plugin Bootstrap Select Picker, which allow (as the same of the normal select control) to select multiple values.

If I call: `$('#items).val()` I'll an array of the values selected in the select control:

```
["1", "2"]
```

I would like to include each value in another object like:

```
var main = {
   items: $('#items').val()
}
```

how can show also a structure like this:

```
[ { id: 1 }, {id: 2} ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to build a javascript object using an array and the map function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006748/how-to-build-a-javascript-object-using-an-array-and-the-map-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use map method and change it into object

```js
let arr = ["1","2"];
    arr = arr.map(num => ({id:parseInt(num)}));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
items.map(id => ({id: Number(id)}))
```

Answer (score 1):

The map iterates over every object and stores an object with the id of every visited element in the array and then prints it

```js
var a=["1", "2"];
console.log(a.map((e)=>({id:Number(e)})))
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22085740)

Answer (score 1):

Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var items = $('#items').val()
console.log(items);
// ['1', '2']
var main = {
   items: items.map(function(item) {
       return { id: parseInt(item, 10) }
   })
}
console.log(main.items);
// [ { id: 1 }, {id: 2} ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```js
let array = ["1","2"];
console.log(array.map((x)=> {return{id:Number(x)}}));
```